# How to add background color to the text output of javascript switch statements?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a string of code which is working and the correct outputs are showing on the site. If case 3 is correct and "Accepted" is printed, I have to add a green background to the text that says "Accepted". How can I do this? Thanks

```
getLatestMessage(thread: Thread): string {
    const message = thread.messages.slice().reverse()[0];

    if (message && message.type === 0) {
        return message.content;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

getLatestSystemMessage(thread: Thread): string {
        const message = thread.messages.slice().reverse().find(m => m.type !== 0);

        const isUserOwner = thread.project.user.id === this.user.id;

        let content = '';

        if (message) {
            switch (message.type) {
                case 1:
                    if (<any>message.content > 0) {
                        content = isUserOwner ?
                            `Offered you $${message.content}` :
                            `You offered $${message.content}`;
                    } else {
                        content = isUserOwner ?
                            `Offered to translate for free` :
                            `You offered to translate for free`;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    content = isUserOwner ?
                        'Cancelled offer' :
                        'You cancelled your offer';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    content = isUserOwner ?
                        'You accepted the offer' :
                        'Accepted';
                    break;
                case 4:
                    content = isUserOwner ?
                        "You accepted another translator's offer" :
                        "Accepted another translator's offer";
                    break;
            }
        }
```

And here is the template

```
<p class="mb-0"><strong>{{getLatestSystemMessage(thread)}}</strong></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If background colour needs to be applied just on the basis of text value i.e "Approved",
you can use template variable in your html content as

```
<p class="mb-0">
    <strong #t1 [ngClass]="{'bg-green': t1.innerText === 'Approved'}">{{getLatestSystemMessage(thread)}}</strong>
</p>
```

Define a class bg-green

```
.bg-green {
  background: green;
}
```

**Alternate solution (less recommended)** is to pass this template reference to getLatestSystemMessage function as second param and in case 3 of switch, use

```
t1.classList.add('bg-green');
```

**Note:**

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS. Depending on what templating system you just need to set it based on the variable value.

```
const statusBg === "Accepted" ? "style="background: green"":"";

<p class="mb-0" {{statusBg}}><strong>{{getLatestSystemMessage(thread)}}</strong></p>
```

Comment: I tried it with `const statusBg === "Accepted" ? "style="background-color: green"";` but it doesn't work